# Cannot find module './build/Release/hdf5' in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules

I installed the hdf5 node library, and it looked like it is in place. I am able to type `require('hdf5')` in command line, but when I run the electron wrapper, it gives me the error: Cannot find module './build/Release/hdf5'.

What could be the problem?

Even though the module is in my local directory, when I run the code with Electron, There is not such module under node_module.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU9Tc.png)

Comment: Your having this problem after it is packaged or in your development?

Comment: The problem happens in my development. Once I try to run `npm start` with Electron, this error occurs.

Comment: did you run `npm install hdf5 --save` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but still no change. One thing I notice when I open the inspector in Electron is that there is no hdf5 folder under node_modules even though I have that module locally.

Comment: What do you mean you have it locally? node_modules should be in the root folder of your electron app.  It should also copy the required items to the package output (although I am struggling to get this part to work)

Comment: The node_modules folder is in the root folder of my electron app. But when the app is running, only 2 modules in the folder is loaded as shown in the screenshot.